# Project working with Git, is their any better approaches or is this possible?

Tags: git

> ***Introduction***

Currently , I am using git for R&D.

I am writing on CreateJs to make some HTML5 game for my job. Let say, I have do 5 story and each story have a unique theme and 4 games, and the 4 games is very similar.

I want to make an abstraction on the top of CreateJS API to fit my project. That is,I want to write a standard basic abstraction on my game and call it directly on my projects. To ensure each game can run independently, safely and IDE friendly, I would not like to pull out the **core** for sharing the same core in 4 games. But most likely, the core should be the same.

```
          Story1
          |－－－－game1
          |－－－－|－－－－core
          |－－－－|－－－－|－－－－ abstraction class
          |－－－－|－－－－controller/models
          |－－－－game2
          |－－－－|－－－－core
          |－－－－|－－－－|－－－－ abstraction class
          |－－－－|－－－－controller/models
          |－－－－game3
          |－－－－|－－－－core
          |－－－－|－－－－|－－－－ abstraction class
          |－－－－|－－－－controller/models
          |－－－－game4
          |－－－－|－－－－core
          |－－－－|－－－－|－－－－ abstraction class
          |－－－－|－－－－controller/models
```

abstraction class maybe:
createjs_actor

createjs_button

createjs_dialog

createjs_draggable_item

createjs_droppable_item

createjs_switch

.... so on, so that I can easily extend it,let say ,

```
  Hero extends CreatejsActor {}

  Walker extends CreatejsActor {}
```

These classes must need to revised / add more functions later if the user requirements has changed.
To prevent from updating these classes by copy&paste the files to each game folder manually

> **I decided to do this on git:**

1. Each story has its own **repository**
2. implement the basic structures of the each story in **master**
3. create a **branch** on each game(i.e. **game1,game2,game3,game4**) and these branches will never be merged but will pull some update on master

> **Question: Is their any better approaches or is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easier to just have a separate repository for `core` and each of the games. If you want to tie the games to some specific version of the `core`, try using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). You'll just have to put `core` in a subdirectory then.

Comment: thanks for answering,
The submodule is really suitable! 
Is that a standard approach that each game has its own repository? 

as i am quite new to git, is any one will create a branch that never be merged? or are there exist an element between branch and repository

Comment: You could use separate branches, but in reality... there's not much difference between branches you never merge and separate repositories.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using Git Submodules is to package up your core module as an *npm package*. It would be its own Git repo, you can put a version number on it, and you can reference it in your individual projects.

For development, you can use something like `npm link` to link to the core module.

Using modules is the standard approach for using reusable libraries.

Note: You can do this using `npm` for server-side libraries, or something like `bower` for client-side libraries. The concepts are the same, they just a different tool and configuration file.